# WebRoar and Apache2 on the same port. Best practice?

Tags: ruby, apache2, webserver, port

i purchased a root server machine with one public ip address. on this machine i have installed webroar to deploy ruby on rails applications. webroar is running on port 80 and 2 rails applications are deployed.

so, now i want to install apache2 on port 80. other domains should root to apache. i know i can install apache2 as an reverse proxy on port 80, change webroar to port 3000 and do a routing with the reverse proxy.

my other solution is a second public ip address. the old for webroar and ruby on rails and the new one for apache2.

which solution would you prefer and why?

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Well, WebRoar may well be a great product, but I've never heard of it. For that reason alone I would prefer apache and mod proxy.